# How to browse a special CRUD folder

Tags: yii2

i just have created several CRUD's with gii. Everything works fine, except one table called l_textbaustein_art.
Controller has been created by name

```
LTextbausteinArtController
```

Folder,where all CRUD's have been put in has been named

```
ltextbaustein-art.
```

However I try to call CRUD's I'll get error like this:

```html
Not Found (#404)
Seite nicht gefunden.

The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
```

I tried following URL's:

```
http://localhost/Yii2_perswitch/frontend/web/yiic.php?r=ltextbaustein%2Findex
http://localhost/Yii2_perswitch/frontend/web/yiic.php?r=ltextbausteinart%2Findex
http://localhost/Yii2_perswitch/frontend/web/yiic.php?r=ltextbaustein-art%2Findex
http://localhost/Yii2_perswitch/frontend/web/yiic.php?r=ltextbaustein_art%2Findex
```

Everything failed. Any ideas,how to fix this? 
P.S.: I renamed index.php in folder /frontend/web to yiic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming rules for accessing controller action need a `-` for each Upeercase in controller/action name so in your case

you should use

```
  l-textbaustein-art/your-action
```

see this guide for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#controller-class-naming

Answer (score 0):

You also need to rename the crud folder to : l-textbaustein-art